# DD-WRT firewall rule configuration

Tags: dd-wrt, iptables

I'm using DD-WRT on my linksys router.

I want to limit each user on my network to 200 connections at any given time. Does anyone know the rules I enter the firewall in DD-WRT admit panel.

I tried the following with no luck:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -s -d 192.168.1.0/24 -p tcp -m connlimit --connlimit-above 150 -j DROP

iptables -I FORWARD -s -d 192.168.1.0/24 -p udp -m connlimit --connlimit-above 50 -j DROP
```

Comment: I think that `ipt_connlimit.o` in included in the commercial version of DD-WRT so these lines basicly don't do anything.

Comment: Not an answer, but assuming the command works (ie the connlimit module is loaded), the commands you have issued would limit the entire class C to 150 simultaneous connections.  You would probably want a separate line for each address (maybe script it with a for loop ???)   Also I doubt you can "connection limit" UDP connections as UDP is stateless.  Depending on what you are trying to do, maybe you can do something with QoS ?

Comment: You may need to do this on the OUTPUT chain, since you are wanting to limit connections that begin FROM your network to the outside.

Answer (score 0):

Use the DD-WRT Script generator
http://www.icpnet.pl/~robsonn/generator.zip

just follow the instruction in the software, it will generate the firewall script that you can copy and paste into DD-WRT firewall script.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```sh
iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -s 192.168.1.0/24 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 200 -j DROP
```